# User firendly category selector in post options in Silverstripe cms

Tags: silverstripe-4, blog-post

I would like to change the behaviour of the select box for selecting Post categories within the Post Options in Silverstripe cms. Currently I can find and select the categories only if I know them beforehand. That is the when I enter a letter it starts to populate the select box with the categories that contain that letter.
I would like to populate the select box with all categories by default. And still maintain multi select option. Has this option been considered yet or should I develop my custom category selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're specifically referring to the [silverstripe/blog](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog) module.

The categories field is a `TagField` from the [silverstripe/tagfield](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-tagfield) module. In the `BlogPost` class, the field is set to lazy load:
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/blob/0f8aefb0920812f4f9cc03bba5a0ed4b7b6df205/src/Model/BlogPost.php#L350

You can override that in your project by applying an extension to `BlogPost` and turn lazyloading off for that field:

**app/_config/extensions.yml**

```yaml
SilverStripe\Blog\Model\BlogPost:
  extensions:
    - App\Extension\BlogPostExtension
```

**app/src/Extension/BlogPostExtension.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Extension;

use SilverStripe\Core\Extension;
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;

class BlogPostExtension extends Extension
{
    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        $fields->dataFieldByName('Categories')->setShouldLazyLoad(false);
    }
}
```

You might want to do the same for the `Tags` field while you're at it.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed. I even found additional options (canEdit,..) :)